# Prove from first principles that a guitar string will vibrate at a constant frequency

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators, string, continuum-mechanics, vibrations

From experience I am aware that a taught string will generally vibrate with a constant frequency. I wanted to prove this by considering the relation of distance from the resting position, and its subsequent velocity (or velocit**ies** if non-constant) away from that initial extension.

I realize a suitable end goal would be to prove that a taught string will take the same amount of time to reach its opposite maximum for an ideal range of initial extensions, but I do not have the relevant background to lay out the actual math. What math is involved and how is it composed?

Comment: Have you seen a demonstration that for small displacement a taught string obeys the wave equation?

Comment: Consider a finite length of string. For each infinitesimal mass element, you write down its equation of motion (i.e $F=ma$). You would obtain a partial differential equation (PDE) known as wave equation. Solve the PDE with your boundary conditions and initial conditions. Then you get what you want.

Comment: It is easy enough to show that standing waves form with a discrete spectrum. It's a bit harder to show that the rest of the spectrum is strongly damped.

Comment: What do you mean by "from first principles"? There might be several derivations to reach this conclusion.

Comment: Why should first principles be unique?

Comment: They do not need to be unique. But if you want an answer, you should set a framework for it.

Comment: Isn't this the condition of resonance frequencies, and standing waves? All other frequencies get damped, and interfered with their reflections, and only certain frequencies can resonate, preventing much dampening?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're asking about the velocity of the actual string, and not the wave on it.  If I paint a dot on a guitar string and deflect that dot away from equilibrium, it sounds like you're asking whether that dot reaches the opposite maximum displacement in the same interval of time regardless of how far you pull it away from equilibrium.  If that's the question, the answer is yes.  This assumes a linear restoring force on the string, which is a very accurate approximation for actual strings in typical use-case scenarios.  Under such conditions the resulting differential equation has a period that is independent of amplitude of motion.

If you're interested in the formation of a wave on the string, or the rate at which that wave progresses along the string (wave speed), here is a link to a chapter of a book I wrote in which they're derived: https://www.geogebra.org/m/nyssufjx#material/S2NjxeJh.

If you are interested in all the waves that can form on the string, that depends on boundary conditions.  The locations and types of supports affect the answer since you end up with waves bouncing back and forth and meeting up - over and over.  The easiest way to handle that math is with phasor diagrams.